# Trying to use Queue for inserting values in cassandra python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cassandra, insert, queue

I am using cassandra to store the data i get from client program. I have a server program where i run threads for inserting values but without a queue it doesn't work as expected but i tried using queue, not sure where i am going wrong. Can someone tell me how to access insert statement multiple times.

client program:

```
import socket
import threading
import client_to_orc
import json
import pyangbind.lib.pybindJSON as pybindJSON

def con_server(server_host, server_port, thread_num):
    server_address = (server_host, server_port)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    #print(sock.getsockname())
    ---
    # sw is the packets code comes here

    ---
    packet=(pybindJSON.dumps(sw))     ----> Data in string format

    sock.sendto(packet.encode("Utf-8"), server_address)
    data = sock.recv(4096)    
    data = data.decode()
    print('Client:' + data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER_ADDR = ("localhost", 4242)
    threads = []
    for thread_num in range(10):
        thread_args = (SERVER_ADDR[0], SERVER_ADDR[1], thread_num)
        t = threading.Thread(target=con_server, name='con_servr', args=thread_args)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Edited server:

```
def insert_Vmac(msg):
    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['172.17.0.2'])
    session = cluster.connect()
    id=1
    session.execute("""INSERT INTO mykeyspace.hello(PacketID, PacketValue)
    VALUES(%s,%s)""",
    (id,msg))

def talkToClient(ip):
    logging.info("sending 'clients we received your data' to %s",ip )

    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto("ok".encode('utf-8'), ip)

def listen_clients(Host,port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((Host,port))
    client_list=[]
    while True:
        msgg, client = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        message = msgg.decode("utf-8")
        msg = json.dumps(message)

        print('connected with : ' + client[0]+ ':' + str(client[1]))
        for line in msg:
            cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['172.17.0.2'])
            session = cluster.connect()
            id = 0
            query = SimpleStatement("""INSERT INTO 
                  mykeyspace.hel(PacketID, PacketValue)
                  VALUES(%s,%s)""" %(id, msg))
             session.execute_async(query)
         print('hello inserted')
         t = threading.Thread(target=talkToClient, args=(client,))
         t.start()

if __name__=="__main__":
    t2 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=listen_clients, args=("localhost", 4242,))
    t2.start()
```

The Edited code stores the data only once. But i am sending data for 10 times but it doesn't store all the data.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same id for all requests so each write will overwrite the previous entry. That's why you only retrieve one row when you read the data.

That's with the assumption that "id" in your case is the PRIMARY KEY in your table.

Comment: I also thought this is the problem, but I tried to use uuid.uuid(1) for generating unique IDs for each insert call but didn't work.